# Getting files (and its attributes) in a directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to get a list of files within a directory but I need to know if the file is a directory, when it was last modified, and offcourse its name :) . So I tried this:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/nacho4d/Desktop/"];
NSArray *urls = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:directoryURL 
                      includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey, NSURLContentModificationDateKey, nil] 
                                         options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles 
                                           error:nil];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *name;
NSDate *modificationDate;
NSNumber *isDirectory;
for (NSURL *url in urls) {
    if (![url getResourceValue:&name forKey:NSURLNameKey error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"name: %@", [error localizedDescription]);error = nil;
    }
    if (![url getResourceValue:&modificationDate forKey:NSURLContentModificationDateKey error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"modificationDate: %@", [error localizedDescription]); error = nil;
    }
    if (![url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"isDirectory: %@", [error localizedDescription]); error = nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", name, modificationDate, isDirectory);
}
```

However I always get `(null) (null) (null)`, no errors but no data ;(

I wonder what is wrong here?

PS: I am aware of `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` and `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` but I think that is not the best way of doing this, is it? 
I plan to use this in folders that can contain a large number of files so I would like to do this the most efficient way possible.

#### Edit for iOS5 and later

As @jeremyP pointed, [According to the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURL) the method is unimplemented in iOS4 but since iOS5 and later it seems to work properly:

> **Availability**
>   Available in iOS 5.0 and later. (Symbol is present in iOS 4, but performs no operation.)

This question was done when iOS4 was the latest I think. Now in iOS 5
and 6 Everything works as expected :)

Comment: Is this an iOS or Mac OS question? note that by Apple documentation, this method is not implemented in iOS.

Comment: I am trying to do this in the iPhone. Please see the fourth comment on Jeremy's answer

Comment: Please use the cocoa-touch tag for iOS questions. The cocoa tag is for Cocoa on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't the answer to your question but your error checking should look like this:

```
if (![url getResourceValue:&name forKey:NSURLNameKey error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"name: %@", [error localizedDescription]);error = nil;
}
```

**Edit**

Couldn't figure out what the problem was, but have just reread [the documentation on the method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW39).  The important sentence is the one under discussion that says:

> This method is unimplemented in iOS, so it performs no operation.

Comment: I just updated the code :) Any thoughts why this is not working?

Comment: I honestly can't see anything wrong with the code.  Can you try logging the NSURL as well as the resource values.

Comment: Ohh!!... I see. But if `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` is unimplemented then how can I get file attributes that were pre-fetched in `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:` method? Do I really need to use `attributesOfItemAtPath:error` ?

Comment: Yes, you should do it and the NSDictionary "file manager" methods to easily retrieve the returned dictionary values.

Comment: Just adding some important info from the docs: 
`Available in iOS 5.0 and later. (Symbol is present in iOS 4, but performs no operation.)` This question was done when iOS4 was the latest I think. Now in iOS 5 and 6  Everything works as expected :)